# C# String Interpolation with HTML Tags - Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, string-interpolation

In the Blazor framework, can one do string interpolation with HTML tags? For example, I want to run a loop that prints a sentence using different colors, but this does not seem to work (since it does not seem the correct approach).

```sh
@page "/HJS"
<h3>HateJS</h3>

<div>
    @foreach(string colorX in colors)
    {
        <p style=$"color:{colorX}">@hateJS</p>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private string hateJS = "I hate JS";
    private string[] colors = { "blue", "red" };
}
```

If this is not the correct/appropriate approach, then what is it?

Comment: It can be done! Try `style="color: @(colorX)"`

Comment: With string interpolation, it would be: `style="@($"color: {colorX}")"`

Comment: Useful reference: https://blazor-university.com/components/literals-expressions-and-directives/

Comment: Doesn't `<p style="color:@colorX">@hateJS</p>` also work?

Comment: Blazor uses Razor syntax, just like Razor Pages. Code blocks must always start with `@`. Without that, `<p style=$"color:{colorX}">` is just an HTML element with an invalid style value

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll give a more extended overview, in case it may be helpful for others.

---

Let's say you have the following variables defined:

```csharp
var colorEnum = Color.Danger;
var colorString = "red";

var colorStyle = "color: red";
var bgColorStyle = "background-color: yellow";

var classSuccess = "text-success";
var classError = "text-danger";
var classEnd = "text-end";

var customize = true;

var height = 1.5;
```

##### Summary

| Native attributes | Blazor component parameters |
| --- | --- |
| *Attribute examples*: | *Parameter examples*: |
| **`style`** (expecting `string` value) | **`Style`** (expecting `string` value) |
| **`class`** (expecting `string` value) | **`Color`** (*not* expecting `string` value) |
|  |  |
| *Value **equals** variable:* | *Value **equals** variable*: |
| `style="@colorStyle"` | `Style="@colorStyle"` |
| `class="@classSuccess"` | `Color="colorEnum"` |
|  |  |
| *Value **contains** variable:* | *Value **contains** variable:* |
| `style="color: @colorString"` | `Style="@($"color: {colorString}")"` |
| `style="height: @(height)rem"` | `Style="@($"height: {height}rem")"` |
| `class="@classSuccess fs-3 @classEnd"` | `Style="@($"{colorStyle}; {bgColorStyle}")"` |
|  |  |
| *Value **equals conditional expression***: | *Value **equals conditional expression***: |
| `style="@(customize ? colorStyle : "")"` | `Style="@(customize ? colorStyle : "")"` |
| `class="@(customize ? classError : "")"` | `Color="@(customize ? colorEnum : null)"` |
|  |  |
| *Value **contains conditional expression***: | *Value **contains conditional expression***: |
| `style="color: @(customize ? colorString : "blue")"` | `Style="@($"color: {(customize ? colorString : "blue")}")"` |

##### Details

For **native elements** (e.g. `<p>`, `<div>`), the `@` notation works fine as part of an attribute's value:

```
<p style="color: @colorString">...</p>
<p style="color: @colorString; background-color: @colorString">...</p>

<p style="@colorStyle">...</p>
```

If your variable needs to be "concatenated" with a string, the `@()` notation is needed:

```
<p style="height: @(height)rem">...</p>
```

---

For **Blazor components** (either provided by Blazorise or self-made), the approach is slightly different.

Let's say you've defined a component `MyComponent` with parameters `Color MyColor` (enum value). `MyComponent` will interpret the provided value for `MyColor`, and therefore, the variable can be used directly:

```
<MyComponent MyColor="colorEnum" /> // will be interpreted as Color.Danger
```

If `MyComponent`'s parameter is `string MyColor` instead, the provided value is interpreted as a `string` unless you specifically say that it's a variable using the `@` notation:

```
<MyComponent MyColor="@colorString" /> // will be interpreted as "red"
<MyComponent MyColor="colorString" /> // will be interpreted as "colorString"
```

In such a component parameter, you cannot mix strings and variable values as easily as you can in an element attribute (as in the very first example). For a component parameter, the more complex string interpolation notation `@($" { }")` needs to be used.

Let's say you have  a component parameter `MyStyle` that is used to set the `style` attribute inside `MyComponent`:

```
<MyComponent MyStyle="@($"color: {colorString}")" />
```

If you need to include a conditional expression, the `{ }` part needs to be expanded to `{( )}`:

```
<MyComponent MyStyle="@($"color: {(count > max ? "red" : "blue")}")" />
```

As for native elements, when providing the value of an *attribute* of a component (e.g. the `style` attribute), you can still use the easy notation, as seen in the firstmost example of this answer:

```
<MyComponent style="color: @(colorString)" />
```

(NB: Using attributes on components is not something you can do out of the box; handling that is not covered by this topic.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach with minimal amount of coding and without string interpolation, this should be a fine solution

```
<div>
    @foreach(string colorX in colors)
    {
        <p style="color:@colorX;">@hateJS</p>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question, as "Astrid E. (https://stackoverflow.com/users/17213526/astrid-e)" pointed out in the comments, is to either make it as:

```sh
<p style="color:@(colorX)">@hateJS</p>
```

Or:

```sh
<p style="@($"color:{colorX}")">@hateJS</p>
```